# Running Score / Quiz game

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am a beginner coder, and I am working on this quiz-type program. It needs to ask pre-created questions, and then check if you got the right answer, adjust your running score, and then show the next problem. I finished everything else, but the part that is getting me stuck is this part.

```html
<!doctype html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Group Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script text="text/javascript">
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            document.write(a, "/", b)  
            function score() {
                
            
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
              
            if (document.question.one.value=="10") {
                ++a;
                ++b;
               
            }
            else{
                ++b;
                
            }
            document.write(a, "/", b)
            }
        </script>
        
        
        <form name="question"><br>
            <input type="text" name="one"/><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="score()" />
            
            
        </form>
```

I picked 10 in the IF statement just to see is the increment works, but what happens when I do input 10 into the text input, the page reloads, showing only the created fraction and no buttons or text inputs. How can I make it so the score or fraction runs along, and does not need a complete page reload to increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) as it clears all document to write new content. Instead you should change inner text content of some DOM element, like `div`. For example:

```html
<form name="question">
    <div id="score"></div>
    <input type="text" name="one" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="score()" />
</form>

<script text="text/javascript">
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    
    write(a, b);

    function score() {

        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;

        if (document.question.one.value == "10") {
            ++a;
            ++b;
        } else {
            ++b;
        }
        write(a, b);
    }
    
    function write(a, b) {
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = a + "/" + b;
    }
</script>
```

In above code I introduced helper function `write` which displays scope text in the `div#score` div.

Also note that script now goes after form element, to make sure that `write` function can locate `div#score` when it's executed (HTML should be loaded by that time).

Comment: This seems to work, but if I press the button more than once, it stays at 1/1 or 0/1. How do you think I could get it to go 0/2 or 2/2 etc. with each click of the button>

Comment: You need to change the logic of `score` function.

Comment: Do you think you could lead me in the right direction for changing the logic? Do I need an EventListener? @dfsq

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answer, I would recommend the following. If you are programmatically modifying page contents, you will usually save time by using a library which presents a cleaner/more straight-forward interface. One common library for this purpose is jQuery: http://jquery.com/